# Understanding this Inclusive Notation

Tags: continuity, computational-mathematics, spline

I am learning about splines in my computational analysis class, and this question came up:
[image]
I have not seen this notation before (that is "$(-1 \leq x \leq 0.5)$"), and it is confusing me upon whether or not this function is continuous. It looks like the function is open at x=0.5 and x=2, since the brackets are "()" rather than "[]", but the$\ \leq $ signs in the range are throwing me off.

How do I interpret this notation? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If you plug in $x=0.5$ in the first two cases, or $x=2$ in the last two, you notice that $S(x)$ is continuous. So it does not matter if the intervals are open or closed. But the parenthesis for the range in this notation can be ignored.

Comment: @Andrei that totally makes sense thanks! Is this pretty standard notation and I'm just being stupid here, or is this a rather unusual notation?

Comment: I've mostly seen it as $\begin{cases}\text{formula}_1,&\text{condition}_1\\\text{formula}_2,&\text{condition}_2\\\text{etc.}\end{cases}$ rather than $\begin{cases}\text{formula}_1&(\text{condition}_1)\\\text{formula}_2&(\text{condition}_2)\\\text{etc.}\end{cases}$ but it should mean the same. Looks like someone was translating from a natural language and did not go all the way: "$S(x)$ is: $x$ (for $-1\le x\le 0.5$), $0.5+2(x-0.5)$ (for $0.5\le x\le 2$), or $x+1.5$ (for $2\le x \le 4$)" ... (note the brackets you would likely write in English).

Comment: It wouldn't make sense for the parentheses to have anything to do with interval notation; otherwise, why use inequalities? It makes more sense that parentheses were used as a delimiter.

Comment: Would be easier to understand if the parentheses were left out and and the word “for” was added in each line.